# C# how to disable keybinding

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem, key-bindings

The [MenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.aspx) control has the convenient property IsEnabled (inherited from [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590078.aspx)). This allows me to, when appropriate, hide the command exposed by that menu option.

But if that command is also bound to a key (e.g. Ctrl+K), the user can still access it. How do I get the IsEnabled functionality to a [KeyBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding.aspx)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you bind the `KeyBinding` to an `ICommand`, you can just set the [`ICommand.CanExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute.aspx) to `false` (and potentially raise [`CanExecuteChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged.aspx)).

This will "disable" the `KeyBinding` since the command itself will be disabled.

Comment: Yes, this is the most appropriate way of dealing with this problem. Binding a MenuItem to an ICommand and using CanExecute makes sure that all ways to execute that command are disabled if CanExecute returns false.

Comment: @Davio It also has the nice benefit of allowing you to keep the "enabled" logic tied directly to the same object as the execution logic...

Comment: indeed, WPF does a fine job of separating GUI and business logic concerns out of the box, of course enhanced by design paradigms like MVVM/MVC

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you.

Comment: Warning: This solution depends on a certain implementation of `ICommand.Execute`. That is, it requires `ICommand.Execute` to check for `ChanExecute` which is not necessarily the case for every implementation (although I think, this is a good way of implementing `ICommand.Execute`).

Comment: @TimPohlmann The "implementation" here is the suggested implementation of ICommand, though - Execute really should always call CanExecute first.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Do you have an official source for this?

Comment: @ReedCopsey Whether or not there is an official source, the problem is that if you search for "WPF ICommand example" and click the first few links, you will find a lot of `ICommand` implementations which do not check `CanExecute` before executing.