# Disabling global KeyBindings in some controls in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, key-bindings

I have a main window with some keybindings like this:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Command="{Binding RotateCommand}"
              CommandParameter="left"
              Key="L">
  </KeyBinding>
  <KeyBinding Command="{Binding RotateCommand}" 
              CommandParameter="right"
              Key="R" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

The problem is that I am unable to type this letters in any textboxes in that window, keys L and R just call commands.

Is there any way to disable KeyBindings inside of some controls? (Maybe when some controls have a focus).

I search through the internet and find [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d0f08499-2518-40b3-a5fc-17ded19377fd/keybinding-and-textbox?forum=wpf), but I can't get access to CanExecute routed event because I'm using `mvvm` model for command bindings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# how to disable keybinding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706070/c-sharp-how-to-disable-keybinding)